# Angular 7 vs Angular 8 features comparison

Tags: angular

What is the main difference between Angular 7 & Angular 8?
and the main new thing is **IVY engine** can anyone share this concept with details or link to get clear concepts information.

Comment: Did you check this out? https://angular.io/guide/ivy

Comment: angular has release notes for all of their releases: https://blog.angular.io/version-8-of-angular-smaller-bundles-cli-apis-and-alignment-with-the-ecosystem-af0261112a27

Answer (score 3):

[image]

This is a basic difference between angular 6,7,8

**Get more idea about ivy engine is here: -**
**1)** https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/all-you-need-to-know-about-ivy-the-new-angular-engine-9cde471f42cf

**2)** https://angular.io/guide/ivy

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 8, the term Ivy is referred to their next-generation compilation and rendering pipeline. Angular version 8 onwards, you can choose to opt in to start using a preview version of Ivy.

Angular compiles its HTML in to JavaScript instructions using its compiler then create the DOM according to the component loading. Ivy is the rewritten version of that compiler and its run time environment.

Ivy has significantly reduced the Build Time and Build Size (Bundle Size) and also improved memory efficiency for better performance.

Refer [this](https://angular.io/guide/ivy) for better understanding.